# Emoji Picker Ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, emoji

I saw an app recently that incorporated an emoji picker as a way to react to certain things. I wanted to implement a similar concept into my app, anyone know how I can create something like this photo. I was thinking to use a collectionview and have each cell be its own emoji. Any thoughts or better methods?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/FarisAlbalawi/FAStickers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To put emojis into a collectionView, do such:

```
var emojiList: [[String]] = []
let sectionTitle: [String] = ["Emoticons", "Dingbats", "Transport and map symbols", "Enclosed Characters"]

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    fetchEmojis()
}

func fetchEmojis(){

    let emojiRanges = [
        0x1F601...0x1F64F,
        0x2702...0x27B0,
        0x1F680...0x1F6C0,
        0x1F170...0x1F251
    ]

    for range in emojiRanges {
        var array: [String] = []
        for i in range {
            if let unicodeScalar = UnicodeScalar(i){
                array.append(String(describing: unicodeScalar))
            }
        }

        emojiList.append(array)
    }
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! DragCell
    cell.imageView.image = emojiList[indexPath.section][indexPath.item].image()
    return cell
}
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return emojiList[section].count
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return emojiList.count
}
```

With this extension:

```
extension String {

    func image() -> UIImage? {
        let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0);
        UIColor.clear.set()

        let stringBounds = (self as NSString).size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 75)])
        let originX = (size.width - stringBounds.width)/2
        let originY = (size.height - stringBounds.height)/2
        print(stringBounds)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: originX, y: originY), size: size)
        UIRectFill(rect)

        (self as NSString).draw(in: rect, withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 75)])

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }

}
```

Keep in mind that the unicode emoji ranges might not include all the emoji and you might want to look up and modify the ranges for your app

Comment: I am getting error of unresolved identifier for NSAttributedStringKey

Comment: My answer works in swift 4...there are other answers on other stack overflow posts

Comment: This works in Swift 5, just change the `NSAttributedStringKey` reference to `NSAttributedString.Key` to silence the error of unresolved identifier.