# individual Emoji Symbols Separated into Three Symbols

Tags: swift, macos, emoji, nscollectionview

[image]

If you launch **TextEdit** and choose **Emoji & Symbols** under Edit, you will have a list of 291 symbols for **Smileys and People** under **Sierra** (macOS 10.12).  And I want to list all these 291 emoji symbols with `NSCollectionView`.  Now, I have a string consisting of 291 emoji symbols.  And I separate them to create an array as follows.

```
class SmileyViewController: NSViewController, NSCollectionViewDelegate, NSCollectionViewDataSource {
    // MARK: - Variables
    var emojiArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let emojiString = "..." // 291 symbols
        emojiArray = emojiString.characters.map { String($0) }
        print(emojiArray.count) // 408, not 291
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Running the code above, the array that I get actually contains 408 symbols.  If I take a close look, some of them separate themselves into three symbols.  For example, a symbol named **man with blonde hair** turns itself into three symbols.  One of them is a gender symbol.  [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618487/why-are-emoji-characters-like-treated-so-strangely-in-swift-strings) suggests that a single emoji symbol may be a combination of a few or more symbols.  Is there something that I can do to separate this particular string containing 291 symbols into an array containing 291 symbols?  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A better way to create a collection view with emoji are with their unicode characters. https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode lists the emoji that are available. One implementation I have used is my answer here: [Emoji Picker Ios Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44977646/emoji-picker-ios-swift/44983520#44983520)

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is actually expected. In swift 3.0, emoji is not counted as grapheme cluster. Many emoji are actually a sequence of single emoji connected by zero with joiner. So the `character` property is actually giving you all the single emoji. That's why you have 408 single emoji from 291 *top level emoji*

This behavior of emoji string get improved **a lot** in swift 4. In swift 4, you can directly call `count` to your emoji string and you will get exactly 291 as result

For further information about this topic, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45070201)

Comment: I'm not asking why it happens.  Why are you pointing me to a topic that I've referred to for myself?